# Is there a way to automatically find & replace within Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that's linked to a google form that collects all responses as they are submitted. The answer to the questions on the google form are either "Yes" or "No". I want to Auto Find & Replace all "Yes's" for 1 and all "No's" to 0 within the spreadsheet. Is there a formula or a script I can run that will do this automatically without manually doing a Find & Replace?

Comment: Record a macro.

Comment: Yes, there is. Please edit your question to reflect the specific issues you cannot overcome when implementing your solution. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function replaceYN() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Linked 1');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++) {
      if(vA[i][j].toString().toLowerCase()=='yes'){vA[i][j]="1";}
      if(vA[i][j].toString().toLowerCase()=='no'){vA[i][j]="0";}
    }
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```